# set session timeout in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, session-timeout, servicestack

I'm attempting to use the new ServiceStack session feature. I've read through the help page, but I don't see anywhere that you configure the timeout (aka, the expiration date of the objects in the cache). I expected to be able to set it on the SessionFeature instance created in my AppHost constructor. How is it done? For my application, I need a very short timeout: 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. It's actually on a per-object basis. You set the timeout when adding to the cache collection through the overloads of Add. The default timeout is infinite. At least that's what I see on the cache objects. I'm not sure how the cookie part of the equation works.

Comment: ss-id is temporary and goes away when the browser session ends (i.e. the browser is closed). Whilst ss-pid is meant to be permanent :). When you clear a users server-side cache, the data that is referenced by ss-pid goes away. The data gets re-created under the same key the next time the session is accessed.